# Listening to PropertyChanged events for business logic

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, mvvm-light

My question may be subjective, and I'm sorry if it is.

We are developing a UWP application with some auto-save feature so that each time the user updates something, the whole object is saved to the file system.

In order to do so, I was using the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to detect when a property is changed in my object, or with the `PropertyChanged` event, in the child objects if needed.
And when a change appears via 2-way data-binding, I was saving the whole object.
Something like (the code may contain typos, not representative of the real code):

```
public class ObjectViewModel : ViewModelBase // from MVVM-Light
{
    public ObjectViewModel()
    {
        Section1 = new SectionViewModel();
        Section1.PropertyChanged += SectionOnPropertyChanged();
        Section2 = new SectionViewModel();
        Section2.PropertyChanged += SectionOnPropertyChanged();
    }

    public SectionViewModel Section1 { get; set; }

    public SectionViewModel Section2 { get; set; }

    private void SectionOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

public class SectionViewModel : ViewModelBase // from MVVM-Light
{
    private string _myString;
    public SectionViewModel()
    {
        Property1 = new SubPropertyViewModel();
        Property1.PropertyChanged += SubPropertyOnPropertyChanged();
        Property2 = new SubPropertyViewModel();
        Property2.PropertyChanged += SubPropertyOnPropertyChanged();
        MyString = "some value";
    }

    public string MyString
    {
        get => _myString;
        set => Set(ref _myString, value);
    }

    public SubPropertyViewModel Property1 { get; set; }

    public SubPropertyViewModel Property2 { get; set; }

    private void SectionOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Now I can have listen to the `PropertyChanged` event of my `ObjectViewModel` to save it.
Knowing that the `MyString` property is 2-way bound to a `TextBox`.
And the Property1 & 2 are 2-way bound to a custom `UserControl` (some kind of `RadioButton`).

But my colleague told me that the `PropertyChanged` events were used for binding, and it's bad practice to attach to them to do business logic.
And he removed the listening to `PropertyChanged`, added a listener on `Tapped` event for the UserControl and sends some custom `Message` through the `Messenger`.
Same thing for the string, where he sends a custom `Message` when changed.

I'm really not a big fan of its modifications.

Is it a bad practice to listen to `PropertyChanged` event for business logic?

Comment: I think it's much more valid to listen to `PropertyChanged` than to the `Tapped` event. That sounds like a horrible solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you're familiar with MVVM, you should use commands defined in your ViewModel to react to user actions, and describe your business logic in Model layer. Properties which are used in bindings and "PropertyChangedEvent" should not contain any business logic because it can slow down your development process in future, by turning into "spaghetti code" as you'll add more features and you'll have a hard time to investigate the dependencies between properties.

Answer (score 0):

**PropertyChanged** and **tapped** both all callbacks, none of them is a good or bad practice, so it totally depends on how you are architect your application, if you re already doing it with **PropertyChanged** then keep doing with it there is no harm in it. On the other hand tapped event will also be equally efficient, so to answer your specific scenario :

"NO! PropertyChanged for business logic is not bad practice.